# Is it true that if a divides bc, then there exist prime factors of a that divide both b and c

Tags: prime-factorization

As per title really.

Is there a theorem (or similar) that states that given three positive integers *a*, *b*, *c*, if *a* | *bc*, then there exist prime factors *p1*, *p2* of *a* such that *p1* | *b* and *p2* | *c*?

The specific case where I've come across this is Shor's algorithm, where *a* divides *(x + 1)(x - 1)*.

Comment: Of course not.  Just try examples.  Like $2\,|\,(2\times 3)$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should’ve mentioned that I was talking about non-trivial a, b, c. So not a = b and not a = c.

Comment: Well, that's a major omission. But the problem is still trivial.  $2\,|\,(126\times 10005)$, say.

Comment: Major omission yes, trivial no. I for one certainly don’t think of numbers like 126 and 10005 off the top of my head.

Comment: The actual numbers are incidental.  Take $2\,|\,(6\times 3)$ if you prefer.  Anything of the form $2\,|\,((2m)\times n)$ with $n$ odd will work.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If $a=15$ and $b=165$ and $c=91$ then $a \mid bc$ since $\frac{165\times 91}{15}=1001$ but there is no prime factor $p_2$ of $a$ such that $p_2 \mid c$

It becomes true if the highest common factors (*greatest common divisors* if you prefer) of $a$ and $b$ and of $a$ and $c$ are both greater than $1$.  Here $p_1$ and $p_2$ may be the same prime factor of $a$, for example if $a$ is prime.

Comment: Thanks. So I’m curious as to how it works with Shor’s where *a | (x + 1)(x - 1)* is used to find prime factors of *a* using *gcd(a, (x + 1))* and *gcd(a, (x - 1))*? I’ve accepted your answer though if you could reflect on Shor’s, that be great. Perhaps I’m missing something in the algorithm.

Comment: Actually it turns out the presentation on Shor’s that I was referring to is flawed. It spoke as if there will always exist such factors of *a* when in reality it may not hold (as you’ve shown), in which case the algorithm would require you to select a different value for *a*.